# How to create a Debian live USB with persistence?

Tags: debian, live-usb, persistence

I would like to use Debian wherever I go by installing it on a USB flash drive, but I'm not sure how to make it save the settings and be able to install/update packages without loosing them on reboots.

So I downloaded a Hybrid ISO image from this [link](http://www.debian.org/CD/live/), and I followed the instructions in the [FAQ](http://www.debian.org/CD/faq/#write-usb):

```
dd if=image.iso of=/dev/sdb bs=4M; sync
```

This command copied the image to the flash drive by creating a partition which size is the same as the ISO image (1.3 GB out of 8GB), and the rest of the flash drive is unallocated.

I searched on how to do this, but every tutorial uses a different approach and some of them are outdated and talk about the old usb-hdd image.

So how should I install this hybrid image on the flash drive ?

How should I partition my flash drive to be able to install packages and save settings ? and how can I install this image without using `dd` ?

Comment: [This dated tutorial (2011)](https://www.linux.com/tutorials/creating-debian-live-usb-flash-drive-persistence-non-techies/) described exactly how the result supposed to be in GParted; this was possible with Debian 6.0.0 (Squeeze) using a USB-HDD image. Then again, I can't seem to reproduce the result by using a hybrid ISO image for newer releases of Debian.

Comment: @clearkimura Try [UEFI + BIOS bootable live Debian stretch amd64 with persistence](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/382817/uefi-bios-bootable-live-debian-stretch-amd64-with-persistence). You should award the bounty to user schlimmchen if the answer works for you.

Comment: Hybrid ISOs are images [bootable from CD-ROM](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/El_Torito_(CD-ROM_standard)) 
and bootable from USB devices as they also contain an [MBR](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Master_boot_record). These images are read-only (squashfs filesystem) and thus cannot be written to and they usually have one partition. So you will have to create a second writable partition for persistence, add a `persistence.conf` configuration file and add a "persistence" kernel boot parameter to your grub / syslinux config to detect your second partition.

Comment: @Freddy If you think you can provide a better explanation than posted answers so far--to explain why cloning (using dd or cp) will not work with persistence as described in [the official documentation](https://www.debian.org/releases/stable/i386/ch04s03.en.html)--you should convert your comment into a proper answer instead.

Comment: I tried and tried and tried this with no luck a few years back. Use Ubuntu or Gentoo or something else. Gentoo was the only one I ever had luck with.

Comment: Post-bounty homework: After I continue to read, read, and read various text on the web, and did another few rounds of trial and error, I managed to understand better of cloning (Yes, hybrid ISO _can_ work with persistent on USB [as per official documentation](https://www.debian.org/releases/stable/i386/ch04s03.en.html)). Yet to download and test using Debian 10--I may reach my own answer sometime soon.

Comment: Well, [Knoppix](https://help.ubuntu.com/community/mkusb/install-to-debian#Run_Knoppix_persistent_live) has a system, where an iso will become persistent automatically. I think there is some smart programming behind that, and I have not yet seen it work with a 'standard hybrid iso file' (for example the Debian iso files).

Comment: @clearkimura, I can't find any text about persistent live drives. "The hybrid image on the stick does not occupy all the storage space, so it may be worth considering using the free space to hold firmware files or packages or any other files of your choice. This could be useful if you have only one stick or just want to keep everything you need on one device. Create a second, FAT partition on the stick, mount the partition and copy or unpack the firmware onto it": This is possible and makes a useful read-write partition, but I don't think it can be used for persistence. (I tested with Ubuntu).

Comment: @clearkimura, My definition of persistence: A persistent live drive uses a read-write partition to overlay the ram-drive of the live system. This means that you can install new program packages and do system tweaks, and they will persist after reboot. This is 'more' than to have a read-write partition, where you can store files.

Comment: The Debian GNU/Linux Installation Guide only noted the common use case for the remaining "free space"--that can also be used as a persistence partition, which is implemented by [the Debian Live](https://www.debian.org/devel/debian-live/). Yes, I understand that correctly: A persistence partition is basically a typical read-write partition with some file-level and partition-level configurations (I have read the [Live Systems Manual](https://live-team.pages.debian.net/live-manual/html/live-manual/index.en.html)).

Comment: @clearkimura, I must admit that I have more experience with Ubuntu for persistent live systems. Anyway for some reason I have not been able to use a read-write partition behind a cloned image for a persistent live system, neither with Ubuntu nor with Debian. Maybe I have not used the correct tool or method to create the read-write partition, maybe there is some intrinsic obstacle.

Comment: @sudodus Exactly, I get different results when using different tools. I also found few different issues or bugs that prevented me from creating a new partition using the remaining "free space" after cloning. Hence the post-bounty homework.

Answer (score 16):

## Debian live with persistence.

1. ### First try with official image from `www.debian.org/CD/live/`

   From SE site (standard live):

   ```
   wget https://cdimage.debian.org/debian-cd/current-live/amd64/iso-hybrid/debian-live-10.0.0-amd64-standard.iso
   ```

   From automatic mirror selection (mate live):

   ```
   wget http://debian-cd.debian.net/debian-cd/10.0.0-live/amd64/iso-hybrid/debian-live-10.0.0-amd64-mate.iso
   ```

   Then checksum you download file with https://cdimage.debian.org/debian-cd/current-live/amd64/iso-hybrid/SHA256SUMS...

   Ok ISO filesystem is *read-only*, but there is a little ***workaround***: we could replace non vital *bootparam* by `persistence` in this way.

   - Once file validated !
   - you could alter them by using `sed` for replacing strings in binary.

     ```
     LANG=C sed 's/splash quiet/persistence /;s/quiet splash/persistence /' \
         </tmp/debian-live-10.0.0-amd64-mate.iso \
         >/tmp/debian-live-10.0.0-amd64-mate-persist.iso
     ```

   This will create a modified copy of your *live binary file*, by strictly replacing `splash quiet` or `quiet splash` by `persistence`, everywhere. Ok this will work only while *grub boot command* do contain this two words together.

   But care to not miss the space after persistence:

   ```
   "splash quiet" -> 12 characters
   "persistence " -> 12 characters
   ```

   Or your binary will be broken.
2. ### Install on USB key

   ```
   dd if=debian-live-10.0.0-amd64-standard-persist.iso of=/dev/sdX
   ```

   Then add your *third* partition for persistence:

   ```
   fdisk /dev/sdX
   n           # new partition
   p           # primary
   <Return>    # default: 3
   <Return>    # default: next free sector
   <Return>    # default: last addressable sector
   w           # write and quit
   ```

   This could be run without interaction:

   ```
   fdisk /dev/sdX <<<$'n\np\n\n\n\nw'
   ```

   Format and prepare persistence with `union`:

   ```
   mkfs.ext4 -L persistence /dev/sdX3
   mount /dev/sdX3 /mnt
   echo '/ union' >/mnt/persistence.conf
   sync
   umount /mnt
   ```

   Then eject and try!

   If you use official, unmodified image, for using *persistence*, you have to *interrupt* boot selection:

   Once *menu* screen is displayed, choose your boot option, then instead of <kbd>Return</kbd>, hit <kbd>Tab</kbd>.

   The kernel commandline will be displayed, then add `persistence` with a space, after last word (`quiet`), then hit <kbd>Return</kbd>.

   Unfortunately, as 1st partition is bundled with UEFI and is ISO, you can't modify the boot command.

## Customized Debian live with persistence

You just have to add `persistence` to boot command line, but nothing else!?
There is a way, using FAT and `syslinux`, but you have a lot of data manipulations. It's long and I find this not so well. I prefer:

1. ### Build your own Debian live

   More *regular*, but a little longer (at least for 1st image),

   Note: All this stuff was done under ***root*** user (this must work by using `fakeroot`, but this is not tested there and today).

   ```
   apt install live-build
   ```

   ... and all recommendations.

   I wrote a little `XARGS` function for dropping commented lines:

   ```
   XARGS() { sed -ne '/#/d;s/ \t//g;H;${x;s/\n/ /g;s/^ //;p}'; }
   ```

   First setting `bootparams`, with localisation and arguments for persistence:

   ```
   ExtraBootParams=$(XARGS <<eobp
       boot=live
       config
       locales=ed_WT
       keyboard-layouts=ed
       keyboard-variant=wt
       persistence
   eobp
   )
   ```

   Now your package list:

   ```
   PackageList=$(XARGS <<-eopl
       gnome
       gnome-core
       # gnome-full
       # debian-forensics
       debian-installer-launcher
   eopl
   )
   ```

   Very first step of *`lb`*: create initial tree:

   ```
   lb config --architectures amd64 -d buster --debian-installer-gui \
       true --archive-areas 'main contrib non-free' \
       --bootappend-live "$ExtraBootParams"
   ```

   Now, you have a small tree, you could:

   ```
   printf "%s\n" > config/package-lists/standard.list.chroot \
       $Packages $PackageList
   ```

   Ok, next command will take a loooong time! (Approx 1 hour on my host)

   ```
   lb build
   ```

   If everything's ok, you may find your own *Debian live*:

   ```
   ls -l *.iso
   -rw-r--r--  1 root root 1511817216 sep  7 15:32 live-image-amd64.hybrid.iso
   ```
2. ### Install on USB key (same operation than for downloaded binaries)

   The *'iso-hybrid'* image contains two partitions for UEFI and live mixed in a way both *EFI* and *bios* could boot on.

   ```
   file live-image-amd64.hybrid.iso
   live-image-amd64.hybrid.iso: DOS/MBR boot sector; partition 2 : ID
   =0xef, start-CHS (0x3ff,254,63), end-CHS (0x3ff,254,63), startsect
   or 708, 5696 sectors
   ```

   You could simply put to your USB Key: (Note: ensure first your USB Key is not mounted!)

   ```
   dd if=live-image-amd64.hybrid.iso of=/dev/sdX
   ```

   Then add your *third* partition for persistence:

   ```
   fdisk /dev/sdX <<<$'n\np\n\n\n\nw'
   ```

   Format and prepare persistence with `union`:

   ```
   mkfs.ext4 -L persistence /dev/sdX3
   mount /dev/sdX3 /mnt
   echo '/ union' >/mnt/persistence.conf
   sync
   umount /mnt
   ```

   Eject and try...

## Debian live with encrypted persistence

1. ### Build your own Debian live, but with encrypted *persistence*.

   In order to boot with rootfs `/` on encrypted persistence, you have to add `dm-crypt` module **and** related binaries to *initrd* (initial ram disk) by adding setting `CRYPTSETUP=y` into an `/etc/initramfs-tools/hooks/`...

   I wrote a little `XARGS` function for dropping commented lines:

   ```
   XARGS() { sed -ne '/#/d;s/ \t//g;H;${x;s/\n/ /g;s/^ //;p}'; }
   ```

   First setting `bootparams`, with localisation and arguments for persistence and cryptsetup:

   ```
   ExtraBootParams=$(XARGS <<eobp
       boot=live
       config
       locales=ed_WT
       keyboard-layouts=ed
       keyboard-variant=wt
       persistent=cryptsetup
       persistence-encryption=luks
       persistence
   eobp
   )
   ```

   Now your package list:

   ```
   PackageList=$(XARGS <<-eopl
       gnome
       gnome-core
       # gnome-full
       # debian-forensics
       debian-installer-launcher
   eopl
   )
   ```

   And your package selection:

   ```
   Packages=$(XARGS <<-eopk
       cryptsetup
       cryptsetup-initramfs
       debian-installer-launcher
       firmware-linux-nonfree
       firmware-linux-free
       less
       ssh
   #   openvpn
   #   xtightvncviewer
       gsmartcontrol
       smartmontools
       partclone
       ntfs-3g
       task-gnome-desktop
       user-setup
       sudo
       apt-utils
   eopk
   )
   ```

   Of course `cryptsetup` is required! ;-)

   Very first step of *`lb`*: create initial tree:

   ```
   lb config --architectures amd64 -d buster --debian-installer-gui \
       true --archive-areas 'main contrib non-free' \
       --bootappend-live "$ExtraBootParams"
   ```

   Now, you have a small tree, you could:

   ```
   printf "%s\n" > config/package-lists/standard.list.chroot \
       $Packages $PackageList
   ```

   Ok, next two command will take a loooong time! (Approx 40' on my host)

   ```
   lb bootstrap ; lb chroot
   ```

   Now you could add your module and binaries:

   ```
   echo dm-crypt >> chroot/etc/initramfs-tools/modules

   sed '/CRYPTSETUP=/s/^#//;s/=.*/=y/' -i \
       chroot/etc/cryptsetup-initramfs/conf-hook 
   ln -s ../../cryptsetup-initramfs/conf-hook \
       chroot/etc/initramfs-tools/hooks/cryptsetup
   chroot chroot live-update-initramfs -u
   ```

   Then run final stage (will take some more lot of time ~25'):

   ```
   lb installer ; lb binary
   ```

   Note: If you read `cryptsetup: WARNING: Couldn't determine root device`, it's fine! This mean that *cryptsetup* is installed on your `initrd`.

   If everything's ok, you may find your own *Debian live*:

   ```
   ls -l *.iso
   -rw-r--r--  1 root root 1511817216 sep  7 15:32 live-image-amd64.hybrid.iso
   ```
2. ### Install on USB key

   The *'iso-hybrid'* umage do contain already two partitions for UEFI and live mixed in a way both *EFI* and *BIOS* could boot on.

   ```
   file live-image-amd64.hybrid.iso
   live-image-amd64.hybrid.iso: DOS/MBR boot sector; partition 2 : ID
   =0xef, start-CHS (0x3ff,254,63), end-CHS (0x3ff,254,63), startsect
   or 708, 5696 sectors
   ```

   You could simply put to your USB Key: (Note: ensure first your USB Key is not mounted!)

   ```
   dd if=live-image-amd64.hybrid.iso of=/dev/sdX
   ```

   Add new Linux partion by using free space.

   ```
   fdisk /dev/sdX <<<$'n\np\n\n\n\nw'
   ```

   This will create *partition 3* using free space on your USB Key.

   Then prepare your crypted partition

   ```
   cryptsetup -q luksFormat /dev/sdX3
   ```

   *Enter passphrase*

   ```
   cryptsetup -q luksOpen /dev/sdX3 persist
   ```

   *Enter passphrase again*

   ```
   mkfs.ext4 -L persistence /dev/mapper/persist
   mount /dev/mapper/persist /mnt
   echo '/ union' >/mnt/persistence.conf
   sync
   umount /mnt
   cryptsetup luksClose persist
   ```

That's all.

```
eject /dev/sdX
```

Comment: This is interesting: 1. Are there any `bin` files available for the current versions of Debian? 2. Please let us know, if and how your method works (with the current versions of Debian).

Comment: @sudodus Since Debian 7 (Wheezy), the USB-HDD images were no longer built for release. I can at least confirm that the USB-HDD images are available for Debian 5 (Lenny) and 6 (Squeeze). The USB-HDD images are `.img` and not `.bin`, but I guess these are essentially the same [as per Debian Wiki](https://wiki.debian.org/DiskImage#A.bin_.2F_.raw_.2F_.img).

Comment: Ok, I will rewrite all this, but not today... Sorry.

Comment: @sudodus Rewite finished, and **no**, sorry: `bin` image published on debian.org don't boot with crypted persistence.

Comment: Neither OP or the bounty provider myself had asked for encrypted persistence, just the normal persistence. Regardless, this answer still does not explain how is this different from the hybrid ISO image offered by Debian--why need to build everything from the beginning...?

Comment: @clearkimura ... but encryption on private usb key is cool!!

Comment: @sudodus Sorry for previous misinfo: binary file available to download is capable of using persistence, but you have to ask for at each boot.

Comment: @clearkimura Another edit (hope the last). Added one section concerning available binaries to download and another section using live build, but simplier and without encryption.

Comment: +1; @F.Hauri, I have tried to create the partition for persistence after the cloned part of a USB drive using `parted` and `gparted` without much luck. You show that `fdisk` works (does not destroy the booting of the cloned drive). And yes, I see that it will be necessary to add the boot option `persistence` at every boot because the file system iso9660 is read-only by design. And I agree, it can be cool (even very valuable) to have encrypted persistence for example while travelling.

Comment: @clearkimura I've found a nice solution based on downloaded images, using `sed 's/splash quiet/persistence /'. See edited 1st paragraph!

Comment: @F.Hauri, Thanks for this tip :-)

Comment: @F.Hauri Never mind me; I am rather concerned if end-users will ever understand when this answer will work or will fail to work (yes, that "nice solution" can fail). Myself at present would understand why, but myself from many years ago, like any average end-user, might have disagreed with this answer instead.

Comment: @F.Hauri, I am sorry, but 'this will work only while grub boot command do contain this two words together, but this is alway the case, at least from Debian 6' is not true for the live iso files of Debian 8 and 9 that I have tested. It works well for me with the Debian 10 standard amd64 live iso file.

Comment: @sudodus which one did you test? Standard, gnome, kde?

Comment: @F.Hauri, I tested with the following four iso files downloaded from Debian recently or some time ago: debian-live-10.0.0-amd64-standard.iso  debian-live-8.8.0-i386-standard.iso debian-live-8.8.0-amd64-standard.iso   debian-live-9.6.0-amd64-cinnamon.iso (I found no standard live iso file for Debian 9).

Comment: @sudodus That's strange! I've dropped wrong phrase... I will try to understang what's going wrong... Thanks!

Comment: Since the Debian 10.0.0 live image is no longer available, can anyone confirm if the sed technique works with `debian-live-10.5.0-amd64-standard.iso`? I've successfully replaced the boot parameter, but I'm still prompted to choose a boot option.

Comment: @JonathanHolvey On prompt, hit `tab` key and look command line, if your update is present.

Comment: @F.Hauri yes, I can see the update when I tab at the prompt. However, I need the OS to boot without user interaction. Is this not possible?

Comment: @JonathanHolvey This is not same question! Please ask a new one!

Comment: This is brilliant! Quite useful on smaller devices that doesn't have enough ram to support all changes in tmpfs. From what I've seen the startup scripts look for just any device with the proper FS, so it looks like this could even work with an actual CD or network boot, + properly formatted usb stick (you may still have to edit the cmdline...).

Comment: The technique "1." worked for Debian 12 (`debian-live-12.1.0-amd64-xfce.iso`)

Answer (score 8):

## Cloning and Debian persistent live

[Cloning](https://help.ubuntu.com/community/Installation/iso2usb#Cloning_and_extraction) (copying each byte as it is, creating a one-to-one copy) is a very simple and reliable method to create a boot drive (live drive or install drive) from a linux hybrid iso file.

There is no conventional way to make a cloned Debian iso file persistent, because it has a read-only file system, ISO9660, (and read-only 'partition table').

## Edit 2023-06-12: mkusb-plug for debian 12

**{** The method described at the end of this answer 'Using mkusb-minp (BIOS/UEFI)' is developed further into the shellscript `mkusb-sedd` with the graphical front end [`mkusb-plug`](https://help.ubuntu.com/community/mkusb/plug). This method modifies the content of the iso file while cloning to the target drive, and a partition for persistence is created 'behind' the cloned copy on the drive. While `mkusb-dus` makes good persistent live drives for Debian 10 and 11, its products for Debian 12 work only in UEFI mode (not in BIOS mode alias legacy mode).

**`mkusb-sedd` and its front end `mkusb-plug` work well with Debian 10-12** (there is no problem with with version 12), and for this reason I recommend using this method, when you want to make a persistent live drive with the current version of Debian.
**}**

## Using mkusb-dus (BIOS/UEFI)

**It is possible (and I would say rather simple) to use [mkusb](https://help.ubuntu.com/community/mkusb/) to create a persistent live drive from a Debian live iso file**. mkusb supports Debian 8 or newer, and you should use the current version of mkusb (version 12.3.3 or newer).

- See the details at [this link](https://help.ubuntu.com/community/mkusb/install-to-debian) to install mkusb in Debian.
- There are tips about [persistent live drives made with mkusb](https://help.ubuntu.com/community/mkusb/persistent).
- See also [this link (where Debian is one of the distros listed)](https://help.ubuntu.com/community/mkusb/gui#Linux_distros_where_mkusb_works).

**mkusb** creates a partition table and 5 partitions:

1. NTFS partition for exchange of data with Windows computers (optional size)
2. Extended partition or `bios_grub` partition
3. FAT32 boot partition for booting with `grub` (both in UEFI and BIOS mode)
4. ISO9660 partition containing clone of the iso file
5. **`ext`** partition for persistence, where your modifications (and files) are stored

**mkusb** does the following tweaks automatically:

- The boot option `persistence` (not `persistent` as in Ubuntu)
- The label `persistence` on partition #5 (not `casper-rw` as in Ubuntu)
- The file `persistence.conf` with the content `/ union` at the top level of partition #5.

This structure is created by the bash shellscript `dus-persistent`, when you use mkusb version 12, alias `mkusb-dus`. If you want all the details, install mkusb and read the content of `dus-persistent`, or read it directly via [phillw.net/isos/linux-tools/mkusb/dus-persistent](https://phillw.net/isos/linux-tools/mkusb/dus-persistent).

The default settings of mkusb can be used for Debian 8, 9 and 10, and the persistent live drive will work when booted in BIOS mode and UEFI mode (but not with secure boot).

(In the previous version mkusb 12.3.2 you must set 'usb-pack-efi' manually in the 'settings' menu for Debian 10 in UEFI mode.)

## Using manual setup (UEFI only)

If you want an UEFI only boot flash drive you do not need an installer at all.

**You just need to format flash drive with FAT32 and set boot flag on. Then use whatever is your favorite extraction tool like 7zip to extract & copy ISO to FAT32 partition**. See [Do it yourself](https://help.ubuntu.com/community/Installation/iso2usb#Do_it_yourself) for more details.

I verified this method with the standard live iso file (small, no graphic desktop environment),

```
debian-live-10.0.0-amd64-standard.iso
```

*So this way you can make a USB boot drive with Debian 10 (64-bit).* It will be live-only and boot in UEFI mode.

- Create a FAT32 partition big enough to store the files from the iso file (add approximately 5 % to the size of the iso file)
- Mount the FAT32 partition
- Extract the content (directory tree with all the files) of the iso file to the FAT32 partition

*Now you have a live-only USB boot drive*

- Edit the word `persistence` to the end of the line(s) starting with `linux` in the file

  ```
    /path/to/mountpoint/boot/grub/grub.cfg
  ```
- Create an **`ext2`** partition in the unallocated space (behind the FAT32 partition)
- Put the label `persistence` on the **`ext2`** partition
- Mount the **`ext2`** partition
- Write `/ union` to the file `persistence.conf` in the **`ext2`** file system
- **Unmount** all partitions on the flash drive before you unplug it, or **reboot**

*Now you have a persistent live USB drive with Debian 10.*

---

Command output seen from within the persistent live drive:

```
$ df -h
Filesystem      Size  Used Avail Use% Mounted on
udev            7.8G     0  7.8G   0% /dev
tmpfs           1.6G  9.0M  1.6G   1% /run
/dev/sdb1       4.0G  826M  3.2G  21% /run/live/persistence/sdb1
/dev/loop0      610M  610M     0 100% /run/live/rootfs/filesystem.squashfs
tmpfs           7.8G     0  7.8G   0% /run/live/overlay
/dev/sdb2        11G   38M   11G   1% /run/live/persistence/sdb2
overlay          11G   38M   11G   1% /
tmpfs           7.8G     0  7.8G   0% /dev/shm
tmpfs           5.0M     0  5.0M   0% /run/lock
tmpfs           7.8G     0  7.8G   0% /sys/fs/cgroup
tmpfs           7.8G     0  7.8G   0% /tmp
tmpfs           1.6G     0  1.6G   0% /run/user/1000

$ lsb_release -a
Distributor ID: Debian
Description:    Debian GNU/Linux 10 (buster)
Release:    10
Codename:   buster

$ lsblk -fm /dev/sdb
NAME   FSTYPE LABEL       UUID                                 FSAVAIL FSUSE% MOUNTPOINT                            SIZE OWNER GROUP MODE
sdb                                                                                                                14.8G             brw-rw----
├─sdb1 vfat   USBBOOT     7176-C538                               3.2G    20% /usr/lib/live/mount/persistence/sdb1    4G             brw-rw----
└─sdb2 ext2   persistence 2b324439-d63e-4a19-bf57-d49ecb881828     10G     0% /usr/lib/live/mount/persistence/sdb2 10.8G             brw-rw----
```

You can see that the size of `overlay` matches that of `/dev/sdb2` which indicates that the persistence is working.

## Using `mkusb-minp` (BIOS/UEFI)

It is possible (and I would say rather simple) to use [**mkusb-minp**](https://help.ubuntu.com/community/mkusb/minp) to create a persistent live drive from a Debian live iso file. **mkusb-minp** supports Debian 10 or newer. This simple shellscript is developed from **mkusb-min**. Both of them 'wrap a safety belt' around the cloning process to help avoid writing to the wrong device.

This is a good option, if you do not want to add software via a PPA or in general want to use only tools that you can understand.

- I made this simple shellscript based on the simple cloning method by F. Hauri (described in another answer in this thread).
- See the general description at [help.ubuntu.com/community/mkusb/minp](https://help.ubuntu.com/community/mkusb/minp).
- There are more details at [help.ubuntu.com/community/mkusb/minp/details](https://help.ubuntu.com/community/mkusb/minp/details).

Comment: General information for users: As of today (5 Sep 2019), mkusb 12.3.2-1ubuntu4 is [available via PPA](https://launchpad.net/~mkusb/+archive/ubuntu/ppa/+packages) for Ubuntu 12.04 and newer. SparkyLinux, a Debian-based distro, has the same version in [their repository](https://sparkylinux.org/repo/) as [announced in March 2019](https://sparkylinux.org/mkusb/).

Comment: Post-bounty comment: The `sed` command is just a workaround, and yet nobody seems to comment or explain the limitations. I think copying the solution from other answer is doing more harm than good, unless you can clarify when that will fail to work.

Comment: @clearkimura, I have tested 'all the way' F.Hauri's to 'binary edit' `persistence ` into a Debian 10 iso file, create a partition behind it with `fdisk` and tweak the partition to become a container for persistent data. I can confirm that it works with Debian 10 both in UEFI and BIOS mode, but I cannot say anything yet about previous versions (Debian 8 and 9). I remove the text from the answer and make 'only' this comment about it.

Comment: @clearkimura, Now I have tested Debian 8 and 9. Persistence works with Debian 8.8.0-standard (amd64 and i386) in BIOS mode, but not in UEFI mode, because `sed` does not see the pattern suggested in grub. It would need another pattern (than suggested by F. Hauri). The partition for persistence works, and it is possible to add `persistence` at the grub menu. Persistence does not work with Debian 9.6.0-cinnamon because `sed` does not see the pattern suggested. It would need other patterns.The partition for persistence works, and it is possible to add `persistence` at the grub and syslinux menus.

Comment: A corresponding method using a binary edited and cloned drive with an 'fdisked' partition behind works with Lubuntu Eoan (to become 19.10) but not with Lubuntu 18.04.1 LTS. We can expect it to work with the next Lubuntu LTS (and with the other flavours of Ubuntu) 20.04 LTS.

Comment: Not sure if my comment was misinterpreted, but I just wanted to hint that the `sed` command will not work for everyone. Given that is only a workaround, it is not worth the time to do further testing.

Comment: I have tested `mkusb` 2 years ago, it work perfectly on/for creating a persistent  debian 8 and 9. [here is my answer on U&L](https://unix.stackexchange.com/a/353930/153195)

Comment: Manual install confirmed working with deb 10.8

Answer (score 4):

Why don't you make a new installation of Debian choosing the usb device instead your HDD as the destination? What capacity does your usb have?

I have a Debian LXDE installed and runing in a 4GB usb memory stick, updating the system whenever I want and installing packages when I need them.

Comment: It's an 8GB flash drive, I want to use GNOME, and thought that it would take a lot of space, and the GNOME live image is 1.3 GB only, but my HDD install is larger but I don't know exactly how much, which installation image did you use ?

Comment: @Peter - 8GB should be fine for a default install.

Comment: I used http://cdimage.debian.org/debian-cd/current-live/i386/iso-hybrid/debian-live-7.4-i386-lxde-desktop.iso, since I wanted speed I picked lxde. You have a gnome image there too. Gnome from the usb may be a little bit slow, but if you have plenty of RAM, it will only be slow opening the apps the first time, next time they will open faster. Regarding space, obviously you will have reduce the number of apps you install in the usb to the ones you really use/need, and leave the rest for your home computer.

Comment: By the way, you may want to create your /tmp on your ram instead on your disk, you will only need to add the line `tmpfs   /tmp         tmpfs   nodev,nosuid,size=2G          0  0` to your fstab (change 2G for the size you want it to be and have in mind that the amount you assign to tmp won't be available for the rest of the apps)

Comment: Using *installed system* is not suitable to USB key who have to boot on many different hardware. A real *live* is build in a way to permit multiple hardwares

Answer (score 2):

First of all - I am no Linux guy - just familiar with it more than the average Joe.

You could use yummi installer to create a Debian 10 usb (I used a 16GB stick I had laying around) boot stick, then boot from it.

The once in, insert a large USB stick into a different port (I am doing this as we speak with a 128GB Samsung FIT flash-drive) and then double-click on the Install Debian icon on the desktop.

Run through the normal stuff until you get to the partitioning, then select manual..in the manual partitioning screen ensure your 128GB USB stick is selected (or whichever one you use - make sure it is not the local drive for whatever PC you are using to do this and make sure it is not the 16GB USB stick that the live Debian is currently running on)

Once done delete all existing partitions frm the 128GB usb stick and create the following 3 partitions.

500 MB /boot/efi
1942MB linuxswap
the rest ext2  (mine is 119GB)

---- I wouldn't use ext3 or 4 for a USB stick - not sure why, some Linux guy told me that a few years ago and I stuck with it. If anyone knows why please tell us?

and finally ensure you're boot loader will be installed to the proper USB stick - this was on the same page as the partitioning when I did it and it is easy to miss - for me, it was at the very bottom and I had to change it from the local SDD of the PC I was using to do this to the Samsung 128GB FIT flash-drive. After all that, next...wait about an hour or so (in my case).

If Debian live locks the password is "live" without quotes of course.

It finished while I was typing this so I reboot and log onto my full blown Debian 10 system running from my Samsung 128GB FIT USB flash-drive. With the approx. 10 minutes for usage I've had on it I was able to confirm disk space is as it should be (LOTS) and it seems to be performing a bit slower than my NvMe  local drive but faster than a reguler 7200RPM HDD.

There yah go.

Comment: oh yeah, I used Debian 10 KDE non-free but i suppsoe anything would work this way..am going to pull the stick from my laptop which I used to create it and try it out on my desktop and my web sver to make sure it boots fine across multiple computer manufacturers and is not limited to my laptop we'll see...let you know in 10 minutes or so...

Comment: Worked fine on all systems - I had to disable secure boot on those that had it in their BIOS and enabled (x2 - tested on five systems = 1 older model HP Inspiron, one REAL older model Dell XPS, one Alienware Aurora R4 - secure boot not enabled, one Alienware Aurora R8 - secure boot enabled-had to disable it to get boot to work and one MSI Infinite X also with secure boot enabled and I disabled it). Other than that np. This is for me to use for diagnosis purposes only - otherwise I'd just install it to the NvME and secure boot it from that drive and be done with it.

Comment: You describe in a good way how to create an installed system in a USB drive (installed like into an internal drive). This is a good alternative, but it is not answering the original question of this thread. Anyway, I think your effort is worth upvoting (+1).