# Debian create live persistence through Windows

Tags: linux, debian, windows, live-usb, persistence

I have installed Debian Live onto a USB drive and am wondering how to now create a persistence so that updates and other file are not wiped at reboot. I have looked at [How to create a Debian Live USB with persistence](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/118965/how-to-create-a-debian-live-usb-with-persistence), but it is talking about Debian on Linux.

I install Debian with the [Universal USB Installer](http://www.pendrivelinux.com/universal-usb-installer-easy-as-1-2-3/)

Comment: @Fabby Which link? UUI only has three steps and the question does not mention your selected text.

Comment: Why don't you use your not yet persistent Debian to switch on persistence on your USB drive, then reboot?

Comment: @FerencWágner I have tried fdisk but am new to lui Linux and don't exactly know how to use it.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Check out the [Debian Live manual](https://web.archive.org/web/20151110101913/http://live.debian.net/manual/stable/html/live-manual/toc.en.html), especially the [Using the space left on a USB stick](https://web.archive.org/web/20151110132006/http://live.debian.net/manual/stable/html/live-manual/the-basics.en.html#190) and the [Persistence](https://web.archive.org/web/20151110132019/http://live.debian.net/manual/stable/html/live-manual/customizing-run-time-behaviours.en.html#529) sections, which explain creating a new partition and using it for persistence. Above links for the stable version in English, other combinations are also available from the [project page](https://web.archive.org/web/20151110100849/http://live.debian.net/) (now redirect to [the new homepage](https://www.debian.org/devel/debian-live/)).

Main points:

- a special boot parameter to be specified at boot time: `persistence`
- the volume label for overlays must be `persistence` but it will be ignored unless it contains in its root a file named `persistence.conf`
- to make `/home` persistent, `persistence.conf` could simply contain:

  ```
  /home
  ```
- neither `/lib`, `/lib/live` (or any of their sub-directories) nor `/` can be made persistent using custom mounts. As a workaround for this limitation you can add `/ union` to your persistence.conf file to achieve full persistence.

Comment: Alright. I've managed to create another working (fs=ext2;label=live-rw) partition but it doesn't load on boot, even with `persistent` added to the boot parameters. If I want to use the file system, I have to `mount` it manually every time. Is there a way to load it on boot to a specified directory?

Comment: Persistence is not exactly like an extra mount, but may look like one. Check out `man persistence.conf`. You'll also have to change your FS label (see above), consider `e2label`.

Comment: Yes it works! Finally!