# How to install non-free firmware from Windows via usb?

Tags: debian, wifi, windows, usb, firmware

I have a debian 9 live bootable usb with non-free firmware.  I am able to find my wifi network, but I cannot connect as I am missing the necessary firmware (ralink).  I do not have an ethernet cable, so I cannot directly download the firmware via the terminal on debian.  I need to copy the firmware onto a usb drive from windows and then install the firmware from the usb using the debian terminal.

I have searched for tutorials, but every tutorial (that I have found) assumes that the user is downloading the firmware from a linux os.

In short, this is what I am asking: If I have two files in my downloads folder on Windows, the live iso and the firmware .deb file, how do I create a bootable debian live usb with persistence and the ralink firmware file so that I can use wifi?

I originally burned the iso to the usb with win32 disk imager, and I have EaseUS Partition Master to create partitions if needed.

Comment: from the terminal what is the output of `lspci -knn | grep Net -A2` ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

How to create a persistent debian USB?

You can easily create a live persistent debian USB through the [MKUSB](https://help.ubuntu.com/community/mkusb) ubuntu tool : [How to install mkusb in Debian](https://help.ubuntu.com/community/mkusb/install-to-debian) (there is no dependencies problem )

> or in Debian 9 you may find the following file to edit

```
sudo nano /etc/apt/sources.list.d/base.list
```

and add the line

```
deb http://ppa.launchpad.net/mkusb/ppa/ubuntu xenial main
```

Save Ctrl + O press Enter then Ctrl + X , then run:

```
sudo apt install dirmgr
sudo apt-key adv --keyserver keyserver.ubuntu.com --recv 54B8C8AC
sudo apt update
sudo apt install mkusb
```

Fllow [this answer](https://unix.stackexchange.com/a/353930/153195) to create a persistent USB or see the [Ubuntu docs](https://help.ubuntu.com/community/mkusb).

How to process it?

- Install mkusb on the current live USB and Use a second USB device to create a  debian persistent USB.(the easy way)
- Or install virtualbox on windows , install debian , the guest addition and mkusb , attach  your usb to the virtual machine (it take a long time)

How to get the wifi working:

The `lspci -knn` is required tho know the exact  wifi card model .

Generally to get the ralink working you need the non-free package [`firmware-misc-nonfree`](https://packages.debian.org/stretch/all/firmware-misc-nonfree/download) you can download it from [**here**](https://packages.debian.org/stretch/all/firmware-misc-nonfree/download) then install it through `dpkg`:

```
sudo dpkg -i firmware-misc-nonfree_20161130-3_all.deb
```

Comment: I tried to install mkusb, but i received the error "keyserver receive failed: No dirmngr" when importing the gpg key.  My sources.list file is empty (with the exception of the added mkusb line) and, without internet, I am unable to update it or download dirmngr via the terminal.  I am now back to square one: I need to download dirmngr from another os onto a usb and then install it from there.  This is the same problem I had with the firmware-misc-nonfree file.   I seem to be caught in a catch-22.

Comment: @MattSmith use the virtualbox way it is too long but you can control system + you have an  internet connection to install the required package.